# Reading a Printer Device Context in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, printing, bitmap, gdi

I am able to display and save a screen device to DIB bitmap, and I would like to do the same with a printer device context. I can get a non-null bitmap, but it is always solid black.

Here is the code that allows me to handle a screen device context.

```
        //In size variable we shall keep the size of the window.
        SIZE size;

        //Win32 API functions are imported in classes
        //PlatformInvokeGDI32
        //PlatformInvokeUSER32

        //Get handle of calc.exe window.
        IntPtr hwnd = PlatformInvokeUSER32.FindWindow("SciCalc", "Calculator");

        //Get window dimensions
        PlatformInvokeUSER32.RECT rect;
        PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
        size.cx = rect._Right - rect._Left;
        size.cy = rect._Bottom - rect._Top;

        //Get the device context of Calculator.
        IntPtr hDC = PlatformInvokeUSER32.GetDC(hwnd);

        //Draw on the Calculator surface.
        Graphics CalculatorGraphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);
        Color colorRed = Color.FromName("Red");
        Pen penRed = new Pen(colorRed);
        CalculatorGraphics.DrawEllipse(penRed, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        CalculatorGraphics.Save();

        //Here we make a compatible device context in memory for screen device context.
        IntPtr hMemDC = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

        //Create a compatible bitmap of window size and using screen device context.
        m_HBitmap = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);

        //As m_HBitmap is IntPtr we can not check it against null. For this purspose IntPtr.Zero is used.
        if (m_HBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //Here we select the compatible bitmap in memeory device context and keeps the refrence to Old bitmap.
            IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, m_HBitmap);
            //We copy the Bitmap to the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, hDC, 0, 0, PlatformInvokeGDI32.SRCCOPY);
            //We select the old bitmap back to the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
            //We delete the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
            //We release the screen device context.
            PlatformInvokeUSER32.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
            //Image is created by Image bitmap handle and returned.
            return System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(m_HBitmap);
        }
        //If m_HBitmap is null retunrn null.
        return null;
```

Here is how I get a printer device context:

```
        //In size variable we shall keep the size of the window.
        SIZE size;
        size.cx = 1000;
        size.cy = 1000;

        //Get Printer Handle
        IntPtr PrinterHandle;
        PlatformInvokeGDI32.PRINTER_DEFAULTSW defaults = new PlatformInvokeGDI32.PRINTER_DEFAULTSW();
        PlatformInvokeGDI32.OpenPrinterW("Bullzip PDF Printer", out PrinterHandle, defaults);

        //Get Printer Device context
        IntPtr PrinterHDC = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateDCW("", "Bullzip PDF Printer", "", IntPtr.Zero);

        //Initialize DocInfo structure.
        PlatformInvokeGDI32.DOCINFOW docInfo = new PlatformInvokeGDI32.DOCINFOW();

        //Start printing.
        PlatformInvokeGDI32.StartDocW(PrinterHDC, ref docInfo);
        PlatformInvokeGDI32.StartPage(PrinterHDC);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(PrinterHDC, PrinterHandle);

        Color theColor = Color.FromName("Red");
        Pen pen = new Pen(theColor);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        graphics.Save();

        //Here we make a compatible device context in memory for screen device context.
        IntPtr hMemDC = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(PrinterHDC);

        //Create a compatible bitmap of window size and using screen device context.
        m_HBitmap = PlatformInvokeGDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(PrinterHDC, size.cx, size.cy);

        //As m_HBitmap is IntPtr we can not check it against null. For this purspose IntPtr.Zero is used.
        if (m_HBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //Here we select the compatible bitmap in memeory device context and keeps the refrence to Old bitmap.
            IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, m_HBitmap);
            //We copy the Bitmap to the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, PrinterHDC, 0, 0, PlatformInvokeGDI32.SRCCOPY);
            //We select the old bitmap back to the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
            //We delete the memory device context.
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
            //We release the screen device context.
            //PlatformInvokeUSER32.ReleaseDC(hwnd, PrinterHDC);
            //Image is created by Image bitmap handle and returned.

            PlatformInvokeGDI32.EndPage(PrinterHDC);
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.EndDoc(PrinterHDC);
            PlatformInvokeGDI32.ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
            pen.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();


            return System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(m_HBitmap);
        }
        //If m_HBitmap is null retunrn null.
        return null;
```

How can I draw on the printer device context?
How can I save the printer device context to DIB?

Thank you,

Jacob

Comment: That's a very unusual thing to do.  A fake printer driver with a name like "Bullzip PDF Printer" no doubt doesn't support it.  Works like a raster device, not a bitmap device.

Comment: I have now tried the same code with other physical and software printers and received the same results: the graphic prints successfully, but the DC is not converted to bitmap as I hoped. Printers: HP LaserJet 4100 Series PCL, Apple Color LaserWriter 12/600, Bullzip PDF Printer, DOXPrinter801, and LaserWriter Personal NT v51.8. Printer Ricoh Aficio MP C4000 PCL6 gave an AccessViolationException at PlatformInvokeGDI32.StartPage(PrinterHDC);.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printer device contexts are write-only.

For example, suppose you are printing to a PostScript printer.  You create a printer device context and draw some text on it.  The printer device driver does not render a bitmap containing your text.  Rather, it creates a sequence of PostScript commands to draw the text and sends the commands to the printer.  In other words, there is no bitmap to be copied.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I print large volumes of documents to TIFF programmatically. Sometimes the documents are HTML-based emails containing tables too wide to print on a page, meaning some content is not printed. I was hoping to save a bitmap and then determine if there were any non-white pixels beyond the area that could print to a page.

Comment: Could you load the email into an HTML renderer and ask it for the document width?

Comment: The emails are stored in an Outlook PST. The application that submits emails for printing is an off-the-shelf app called DiscoveryCracker, and it submits the emails to Outlook 2007 for printing. I don't know where in the process I could send the document to an HTML renderer. The reason I wanted to use the device context is that I can inject a DLL into DiscoveryCracker or Outlook and hook StartPage, which uses hDC.

Comment: I'm no Outlook expert, but it seems to be possible to write a macro to run when a message is loaded.  However, if only a subset of the messages being opened are being printed, this wouldn't be much use.  Unlike Excel, it doesn't seem possible to run a macro when a document is printed.  Alternatively, if you're hooking GDI you could hook the text and line drawing functions and check their bounds.  Though this could get complicated if you need to take the mapping mode into account.  Or there may be a cleaner way of hooking into the printing pipeline.

Comment: Getting the coordiantes of ExtTextOut and other text methods is the other way I thought of. I agree that having to take the mapping mode into account will make things challenging. If there is a cleaner way to hook into the printing pipeline, I have not found it. Do you have any ideas? The macro idea is not something I thought of. I will give it some thought.

Comment: Another thought.  Outlook probably uses Internet Explorer to display and print HTML (though it may not).  You could possibly use something like a browser helper object to hook into IE's printing.  Though I don't know if BHO's get loaded by embedded instances of IE.

Comment: Unfortunately, Outlook uses Word's HTML rendering engine. See http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2393/microsoft-takes-email-design-b/